# Inverted density plot when using log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, logarithm, density-plot

I tried using ggplot2 for R to create a density plot, however as soon as I gave the `scale_y_log10()` to get a logarithmic y-axis, the plot appears to have inverted itself.  **How do I correct this to get something more like the expected result shown below?**

### Observed Result

[image: The error Image that I am getting]

### Expected Result

[image: Actual output Image]

#### My code

```
fd <- read.csv('data.csv')
fd_factor <- factor(fd$XDIndicator, levels = c("a","b","c"), 
                    labels = c("a","b","c"))
p <- ggplot(fd, aes(x = KTotal, fill = factor(fd_factor))) +
    geom_density(alpha = 0.2, na.rm = TRUE) + 
    xlab('Total collaboration degree') + ylab("PDf") + 
    scale_y_log10() 
ggplotly(p)
```

Comment: Please share a portion of your data. To get help on this site, your issue needs to be reproducible, so someone trying to help you can just copy and paste from your post